# Sum All Primes Below a Given Number | Intermediate Javascript Algorithm | Recursion

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

**Question**

A prime number is a whole number greater than 1 with exactly two divisors: 1 and itself. For example, 2 is a prime number because it is only divisible by 1 and 2. In contrast, 4 is not prime since it is divisible by 1, 2 and 4.

Rewrite sumPrimes so it returns the sum of all prime numbers that are less than or equal to num.

**My Attempt**

```js
const isPrime = a => {
  
  for(let i = 2; i < a; i++)
    if(num % i === 0) return false;
  return a > 1;
}




function sumPrimes(num, total = []) {
  
  let numVar = num;

  let n = total.reduce((aggregate, item)=>{
    
    return aggregate + item; 
  
  }, 0);

  if(n > numVar){
    return n;
  
  }

  for(let i = 1; i <= numVar; i++){
    if(isPrime(i)== true){
      total.push(i);
    }
    
  }
  
  return sumPrimes(num, total);

}

sumPrimes(10);
```

**The Problem**

1. It says: 'Num is not defined'
2. I am not sure if there are other errors.

**My Question**

Please could you help me find the error, and fix the code to solve the algorithm?

Comment: cause `num` is not defined in `isPrime` ?

Answer (score 0):

This was a simple syntax error identified by @Jonas Wilms (upvote him in the comment above :))!

By replacing the 'a' with 'num' the function was fixed.

```js
const isPrime = a => {
  
  for(let i = 2; i < a; i++)
    if(a % i === 0) return false;
  return a > 1;
}




function sumPrimes(num, total = []) {
  
  let numVar = num;

  let n = total.reduce((aggregate, item)=>{
    
    return aggregate + item; 
  
  }, 0);

  if(n > numVar){
    return n;
  
  }

  for(let i = 1; i <= numVar; i++){
    if(isPrime(i)== true){
      total.push(i);
    }
    
  }
  
  return sumPrimes(num, total);

}

console.log(sumPrimes(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

this simple function may help you,

```js
function isPrime(num) {
  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++)
    if (num % i === 0) return false;
  return num > 1;
}

function sumPrimes(num) {
  let tot = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++)
    if (isPrime(i)) 
      tot += i;
  
  return tot;
}

console.log(sumPrimes(10));
```